# SQL delete call to a third table

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm hitting a block in a project I'm working on.

I'm creating a database editor, and I've added a delete function to each table, and made it so that the delete function deletes all of the entries that use the original tables's primary key as a foreign key. So far, so good. However, I've hit a snag when I go to delete from a  specific table. To summarize:

I have a table, `CUSTOMERS`, that has the PK `CUSTOMERID`.

Another table, `ORDERS`, uses `CUSTOMERID` as a FK, so I go to delete any entries where it's used.

However, a third table, `ORDER_DETAILS`, use `ORDERID`, the PK for `ORDERS`, as a FK.

I'm not sure how to delete entries in `ORDER_DETAILS` only where the `ORDERID` matches the ones that I'm trying to delete in the `ORDERS` table.

How do I do this?

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Use your function recursively.

That said, if the database designer deliberately chose to leave CASCADE DELETE ***OFF***, he might have had his reasons for that choice and those reasons might be the very same why you shouldn't even be trying to mimick that behaviour from within the application.

Comment: How this is typically handled is adding some sort of active flag on the data and marking the records as inactive, then checking for that flag within the application.  As is heavily implied by this answer, one should always be very careful about deletion of data.

Comment: This is for a school project, the professor wants me to make it so the user can delete these items from the tables. Do you know any good tutorials for recursive functions in SQL?

Comment: I meant use the function ***of your editor*** recursively.  If the delete "function" is not in your editor, how did you "add a delete function to each table" ???